Convert Datetime to Date in SSIS
With SSIS, I need to convert the [Birthday] column, which is DateTime at the moment to "DATE" format.
I used a Derived column and chose the column [Birthday] from SQL server with the format below:
1952-09-25 00:00:00.000
But I couldn't convert it with Derived Column expression to Date.
I need to see the format as DD.MM.YYYY
Can anyone help me please with the expression?
Thanks.
These are screenshots from the errors:





I have attached screenshots for both SQL Server destination and CSV destination using same above expression:



Here is the expression :
(DT_WSTR, 2) DAY([Birthday]) + "." + 
(DT_WSTR, 2) MONTH([Birthday]) + "." + 
(DT_WSTR, 4) YEAR([Birthday])


Thanky you but it didn't work.
if i use "/" instead of "." it works but I don't know why when I use "." it shows me this error: [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Derived Column" (2) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Derived Column Input" (3). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with

Also, my last export is in excel file with CSV format. Does it have any influence not to see date format with "dot"?

what's your destination ? For me above expression is running fine whether dumping in SQL server or csv.

Thanks again. I used csv utf-8 as destination but as you see in my screenshots, the data can not export from the Derived column :(

provide the table data just for the date column so i can test on my own
